# Were the ancestors of Malays originally from Yunnan, China?

Tags: indonesia, malaysia

Referring to the post [here](http://www.asiaone.com/print/News/AsiaOne%2BNews/Malaysia/Story/A1Story20111026-307064.html).

> The research discovered that the Malays in these sub-ethnic groups
>   were genetically composed of some Proto-Malay (orang asli Melayu),
>   Semang and Indian DNA, with at least 20 per cent Malay and and 52 per
>   cent Chinese DNA.
>
> "This finding corresponds with a theory that these Malays originated
>   from Austronesia in Yunnan, China," Professor Zilfalil said, " with
>   the first wave of migration from Austronesia to Southeast Asia
>   occurring in 25, 000 BC and the second one in 1, 500 BC".
>
> The professor added that "the Malay language used in the Malay
>   Peninsula, Sabah and Sarawak also belongs to the Austronesian stock".

Is there corroborating historical evidence that the Malays of Malaysia and Indonesia are actually descendants from residents of Yunnan, China?

Comment: The wording strongly suggest that people of Yunnan 25000 BC were Chinese, which I find rather anachronistic. I also doubt that there is much surprise about some correlation in DNA. We are from all Africa, anyways.

Comment: @Greg Not to mention, China was directly populated by peoples that had moved north from South East Asia.

Comment: Is there a reason to question the existing narrative?

Comment: I cannot seem to find this article (the link does not work). Can anyone help?

Comment: @JAsia - The first link Google found that isn't this question is [here](http://www.asiaone.com/print/News/AsiaOne%2BNews/Malaysia/Story/A1Story20111026-307064.html). I was considering posting it in an answer, with an eye toward changing the link in the question if it stays dead. Perhaps this comment will do.

Comment: IMHO, the full article is, well, I'll be nice and say about the level of quality of history one would expect from a mass media publication.

Comment: @T.E.D.- Ok. Thx. I'm not sure they published their findings (i was interested in their methodology), so this could be useful as a followup (for anyone interested): [_Human Variome Project - Malaysian Node_](http://hvpmalaysia.kk.usm.my/index.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will take this question:

- "*Are the ancestors of Malays (of Malaysia) from Yunnan, China?*"

as:

- "*Was the Neolithic (Early [Holocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocene)) expansion of (Pre-) Austronesian-speaking communities into Island Southeast Asia (ISEA) from Yunnan, China?*"

The only answer, at this point, is: **we don't know**.

We don't know because they are competing models to explain how indigenous Malays ([Proto-Malays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Malay)) arrived at Island Southeast Asia (ISEA).

The original hypothesis was ***Out of Taiwan*** by [Peter Bellwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Bellwood), in his book: "*Prehistory of the Indo-Malaysian Archipelago*" (University of Hawaii Press, 1997). His original hypothesis rested mainly on linguistics, namely, the [Austronesian family language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesian_languages), and because of population pressure from agriculture (*agrarian expansion*). Since then he has released a revised 2007 edition, with updates to cover more ground, and freely available as [**ebook**](http://press.anu.edu.au/publications/prehistory-indo-malaysian-archipelago) now.

Since then, there's been **other hypotheses**, not based on agrarian but fisher-forage-trader culture and via southwest China (*Yunnan?*), into Vietnam, Thailand, and finally Peninsular Malaysia. Research from genetic, archaeological and linguistic analysis are inconsistent.

This diagram might help, **left (new hypothesis) vs right (Out-of-Taiwan)**. I have kept title of article and explanatory notes:
[image: approximately 4500–4000 years ago]

The latest book on this '*saga*' is *New Perspectives in Southeast Asian and Pacific Prehistory (Terra Australis 45)*, ANU: March **2017**. Also available as **[ebook](https://press.anu.edu.au/publications/series/terra-australis/new-perspectives-southeast-asian-and-pacific-prehistory-terra)** (free). Book description:

> This volume brings together a diversity of international scholars, unified in the theme of expanding scientific knowledge about humanity’s past in the Asia-Pacific region. The contents in total encompass a deep time range, concerning the origins and dispersals of anatomically modern humans, the lifestyles of Pleistocene and early Holocene Palaeolithic hunter-gatherers, the emergence of Neolithic farming communities, and the development of Iron Age societies. These core enduring issues continue to be explored throughout the vast region covered here, accordingly with a richness of results as shown by the authors.
>
> Befitting of the grand scope of this volume, the individual contributions articulate perspectives from multiple study areas and lines of evidence. Many of the chapters showcase new primary field data from archaeological sites in Southeast Asia. Equally important, other chapters provide updated regional summaries of research in archaeology, linguistics, and human biology from East Asia through to the Western Pacific.’

Comment: Have there been mtDNA and/or Y-DNA studies too? I ask because I have a theory for what they might find, based on those two maps, a map for a nearby (unrelated) language family, and what similar studies have found in the past for other peoples. I'm curious if its right.

Comment: Yes, there is. If you don't want to get into the book (_T. Australis 45_), this might be useful: [_Reconstructing Austronesian population history in Island Southeast Asia_](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25137359), 2014.

Comment: And a more recent (2016) paper using agent-based modeling to reconstruct the flow into ISEA, from genetics-org:[_Reconstructing Demography and Social Behavior during the Neolithic Expansion from Genomic Diversity across Island Southeast Asia_](http://www.genetics.org/content/genetics/early/2016/09/28/genetics.116.191379.full.pdf).

Comment: That "Figure 2" in your fist link is *exactly* what I was guessing happened using only modern language family distribution maps from Wikipedia. Is it linguistic derived too, or genetic? It is SO exact, and the terminology is talking about language families, so I have to assume it is linguistic-based.

Comment: The second link seems to be talking about Indonesia more than about Malaysia. Also, it appears to be talking mostly about the intersection of what I'd linguistically call Austronesians and [Paupans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papuan_languages). Still, its very interesting in what it does talk about. If nothing else it confirms what I've seen from studies in other parts of the world: When two populations meet, there tends to be a preferred pairing (males from X and females from Y were much more likely to produce surviving kids than visa versa).

Comment: Linguistics and genetics is not my strong suit, so I will tread lightly here. This _Fig 2_ is somewhat curious because the intersection of Austroasiatic (green) and Austronesian (blue) is exactly into Peninsular Malaysia (instead of Borneo). The distance from northern Philippines to P. Malaysia by-passing Borneo (which is more immediate) raises questions.

Comment: **Population Genetic Structure of Peninsular Malaysia Malay Sub-Ethnic Groups** -- PLoS One. 2011; 6(4): e18312. - [**source**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3071720/)

Answer (score 0):

Malaysia was under the influence of the Cholas for quite a period of time. There is some Indian percentage in Malaysia, and Tamils did control and are still in Malaysia now.

Check these sources:
https://www.britannica.com/place/Malaysia/People
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chola_invasion_of_Srivijaya

Answer (score -1):

austronesians are not necessarily han chinese, same the other way around. Anyway 25 000 years ago there was neither a chinese nor a malay identity, it was pre-historic. Just various interrelated tribes that intermingled and moved on their own migratory routes. Some future china tribes went north, some austronesian (future malay) went south east. In fact the whole chain from what is now Yunnan-Laos-Vietnam- Cambodia- Malaysia-indonesia comes from the same ausatronesian stock. Their culture is very similar because it came from the same source & tradition. Proudly they also explored & settled into the Indian & Pacific oceans! The north bound tribes started a great culture on the yellow river where rice farming was initiated that spread over the whole Eurasian continent. To each his own, I'd say!

Comment: About 4,500 years.